# Redirect loop error in Pyramid webapp

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a HTML form that posts to a route called add_product, which in turn redirects to view_product:

```
<form action="/add_product" method="post">
....
</form>


@view_config(route_name='add_product', permission='create')
def add_product(request):
    print "TESTING" # <--------------------- nothing gets printed in the console!
    name = request.params['product_name']
    if not Product.get_by_name(name):
        Product.add_product(name, content='')
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('view_product', pagename=name))


@view_config(route_name='view_product', renderer='templates/product.jinja2', permission='view')
def view_product(request):
    pagename = request.matchdict['pagename']
    product = DBSession.query(Product).filter_by(name=pagename).first()
    if product is None:
        return HTTPNotFound('No such page')
    return dict(product=product)
```

When I try to submit the form, I get the error saying that the webpage has a redirect loop. I tried debugging by putting in a print statement, but nothing gets printed to the console.

I also checked the Network Panel using Chrome Dev Tools -- here I see a single `POST` request by `/add_product`, followed by a ton of `GET` requests, again by `/add_product`, before the redirect loop error comes up.

I'm completely at a loss as to what's wrong. Does anyone have a clue?

Edit: my route configuration.

```
config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
config.add_route('index', '/')
config.add_route('register', '/register')
config.add_route('login', '/login')
config.add_route('logout', '/logout')
config.add_route('view_cosmeceutical', '/cosmeceuticals/{pagename}')
config.add_route('add_cosmeceutical', '/add_cosmeceutical')
config.add_route('update_cosmeceutical', '/update_cosmeceutical/{pagename}')
config.add_route('view_product', '/products/{pagename}')
config.add_route('add_product', '/add_product')
config.add_route('update_product', '/update_product/{pagename}')
config.add_route('add_reference', '/add_reference')
config.scan()
```

Comment: Can you also show the route configuration?

Comment: Sure, I've just added it to my post.

Comment: Everything looks fine ... Under which route is the form hosted?

Comment: I'm not sure if its hosted under any route, the form is in my base HTML template where all the other templates extend from.

Comment: You mean Jinja2 templates right? You must be putting in a URL to access the form?

Comment: Yes, Jinja2 templates. The form is in a modal window and all the HTML for it is in the base template, so it's accessible from any URL.

Comment: OK I understand it now and GET requests are **for** what URL

Comment: Is this what you mean? From the request headers: ``GET /add_product HTTP/1.1`` In the response headers: ``Location: http://0.0.0.0:6543/add_product``

Comment: All the GETs are the same?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo; I'm also testing the form which posts to /add_cosmeceutical, which is having the same problem.

Comment: All GET requests are for the same URL?

Comment: Yes, there is 1 POST request then about 20-30 GET requests which are exactly the same, except the last one whose request headers says ``CAUTION:Provisional headers are shown.`` and shows only the Referer and User-Agent.

Comment: Yes, the Request URL is always ``http://0.0.0.0:6543/add_product`` and the Location in the Response Headers is always ``http://0.0.0.0:6543/add_product``

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50003/discussion-between-redbaron-and-bard)